# Python: list containing members of a class

Tags: python, list, class

```
nop = 0
patron = list
def createnew(firstname, lastname, phone, age, gender):
    name = (lastname.lower() + ", " + firstname.lower())
    patron.append(patrons(name, phone, age, gender))
    nop += 1
class patrons():
number = 1

    def __init__(self, name, phone, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
```

There's a couple of parts of my code for a program that holds information about library patrons. What I want to do is store all the members of the class (patrons) in a list (patron), I know the names are a little confusing, I wasn't really thinking, sorry about that. The problem which I am encountering is that when I run the createnew function, I receive an error which says "descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'patrons'" I was under the impression that I could store class objects in a list. Am I unable to do this? If I can do it, what do I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should setup patron as

```
patron = list()
```

Unrelatedly, `nop += 1` will throw an UnboundLocalError. Add `global nop` inside `createnew` More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question)

Comment: Thanks, everyone got it, but you also worked out the second issue. Thanks to everyone for all the help

Answer (score 3):

`patron = list` should probably be `patron = list()`:

Calling `list.append(1)` reproduces an error similar to the one you mention:

```
In [1]: list.append(1)
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'int'
```

To understand the meaning of the error message, you might start by reading about how [methods are descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html). Also note that in Python2 unbound methods such as `list.append` must be called with an instance of the calling class (e.g. `list`). But that is mostly irrelevant to fixing your problem unless you are curious about the nature of the error.

---

`patron = list` makes `patron` equal to the built-in class `list`. 
`patron = list()` makes `patron` an instance of the class `list`.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, list should be list() and you should give nop as an argument:

```
nop = 0
patron = list()
def createnew(firstname, lastname, phone, age, gender, nop):
    name = (lastname.lower() + ", " + firstname.lower())
    patron.append(patrons(name, phone, age, gender))
    nop += 1

class patrons():
    number = 1
    def __init__(self, name, phone, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
```

Comment: nop being an integer is immutable, meaning it gets reassigned when you call `nop += 1` and does not mutate the global variable